# Call by Reference and Call by Value Result

Tags: pass-by-reference, pascal, call-by-value

Well, there was a debate on the below code between me and my friend. We're a bit confused about the output it produce. Can someone clarify the call-by-reference and call-by value result for the below piece of code?

```
program params;
    var i: integer;
    a: array[1..2] of integer;

    procedure p(x,y: integer);
    begin
        x := x + 1;
        i := i + 1;
        y := y + 1;
    end;

begin
    a[1] := 1;
    a[2] := 2;
    i := 1;
    p( a[i],a[i] );
    output( a[1],a[2] );
end.
```

The resulting output of this program in the case that the
parameters are transmitted to procedure p by value-result and by reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Call by Value**

`x` and `y` in `p` are local variables *initialized* with the actual parameters, while `i` is a global variable, so the call `p( a[i],a[i] )` is equivalent to:

```
x := 1  /* The value of a[i] */
y := 1  /* The value of a[i] */

x := 2  /* x + 1 */
i := 2  /* i + 1 */
y := 2  /* y + 1 */
```

and at the end the values 1, 2 are printed since they are the values of `a[1]`, `a[2]` which weren't changed.

**Call by Reference**

Both `x` and `y` in `p` are alias for `a[1]` and (again) `a[1]` (since `i = 1` when the procedure is called), so the call is equivalent to:

```
a[1] := 2  /* a[1] + 1 */
i    := 2  /* i + 1 */
a[1] := 3  /* a[1] + 1 */
```

and at the end the values 3, 2 are printed.

**Call by Name**

Call by Name is *equivalent* to Call by Reference when simple variables are passed as parameters, but is *different* when you pass an expression that denotes a memory location, like a subscript. In this case the actual parameter is re-evaluated each time it is encountered. So in this case, this is the effect of the call of `p( a[i],a[i] )`:

```
a[1] := 2  /* since i = 1, the result is equal to a[1] + 1 */
i    := 2  /* i + 1 */
a[2] := 3  /* since i is now 2, the result is equal to a[2] + 1 */
```

and at the end the values 2, 3 are printed. In practice the implementation calls an anonymous function (a “thunk”), each time it must evaluate a parameter.

**Call by Value Result**

Just to complete the discussion, here is the case for the value-result parameter passing, in which `x` and `y` are initialized at the beginning of the procedure execution with the values of the actual parameters, and, at the end of the execution of the procedure, are copied back to the *original* variables *addresses*:

```
x := 1       /* The value of a[i] */
y := 1       /* The value of a[i] */

x := 2       /* x + 1 */
i := 2       /* i + 1 */
y := 2       /* y + 1 */

a[1] := 2    /* the value of x is copied back to a[1] */
a[1] := 2    /* the value of y is copied back to a[1] (not a[2]!) */
```

and at the end the values 2, 2 are printed.

For a discussion of the different ways of passing parameters, see for instance [this](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/98sp/general/parameters.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could you please provide the result for `call by value result`?

Comment: I've added the call by value-result.

Comment: I didn't know that Pascal supports call by name and call by value result. How is this mode formulated?

Comment: Since Pascal is only in the tag and not explicitly in the question, in my answer I was talking in general about parameter passing for languages wich influenced or were influenced by (the different versions of) Pascal. For instance at least a current Pascal compiler (Free Pascal) has call by value, call by reference (`var`), call by result (`out`) (and also call by constant (`const`)); Algol 60 has call by name; Ada and other languages have call by value-result (`in out`).

Comment: why is it 1 copied back to a[1] ? when you talk about x, in the function body we have x = 2 .  So why 1 is copied back to a[1] from x ?

Comment: @brucebanner, you are correct, the current value of x, 2, is copied back to a[1]. I corrected the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure p(x, y: integer);
begin
end;
```

In this case the varaibles passed as parameters are never modified. They are copied either to two registers (likely x: EAX and y: ECX) or to the stack. (depending on the compiler ABI)

```
procedure p(var x, y: integer);
begin
end;
```

In this case the original parameters are modified. `x` and `y` are pointers to the original variables passed as parameters.